# Probability law of the ordered jump locations of Poisson processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I am looking for a reference on Poisson processes that study the probability distribution of the random times of jumps of Poisson processes. I am particularly interested by the following result, that I believe to be true.

> **Proposition**
>
> Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with $0 \leq t_1 \leq \cdots \leq t_n \leq \cdots$ its random times of jumps and $N$
>   its random number of jumps on $[0,1]$.
>
> Then, conditionally to $N=n \geq 1$, the random vector $(t_1, \ldots ,
> t_n)$ has the same law that the ordered statistics of a vector $(U_1,\ldots, U_n)$ of i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0,1]$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I may miss something, but the $t_i$'s can be greater than 1, $U_i$'s cannot. How can they have the same law?

Comment: My question is conditionally to $N = n$, with $N$ the number of jumps between $0$ and $1$. The event $\{N=n\}$ is equal to $\{t_n \leq 1 < t_{n+1}\}$ (I remind that the $t_n$ are ordered). In particular, the $t_i$ are smaller than $1$ for $i \leq n$.

Comment: I guess the following post is relevant http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529324/289489

Comment: Definitely relevant. Thanks a lot.